# Как спарсить текст с картинки?

Tags: java, парсер, изображения, text

Есть 1000 картинок 2-х типов:
1) с чёрным текстом и белым фоном
2) инверсия первой(с белым текстом и чёрным фоном)

Какой алгоритм использовать для парса текста в .txt файл?

Comment: «Парс», как вы это называете, здесь не используется. Нужно OCR – Optical character recognition.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Логично привести все картинки к одному виду, например все картинки с черным фоном инвертировать и работать только с одним видом картинок, чтобы определить фон можно использовать, например `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, где методом `getRGB` можно получить цвет точки, а с помощью `setRGB` поменять цвет.
2. После того как все картинки стали одного формата, задача превращается в классическую задачу распознавания текста. Рекомендую не пытаться написать велосипед, а просто найти и использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку для распознавния текста (можно даже подключить библиотеку на С/С++ и т.п., если особенно не важна кросплатформеность или вообще вызывать любой исполняемый файл программы распознавния текста, передав ему аргументами картинку).
   Если все-таки хочется руками, то берем что-то вроде `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` и получая цвет точек методом `getRGB` пытаемся написать алгоритм (их море, см OCR и алгоритмы распознавния текста), можно даже машинное обучение использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Быть может есть смысл воспользоваться программами распознавания текста? Например тот же файнридер. Сшить эти картинки в один файл изображения (например, в фотошопе) и разом распознать. Сшить тысячу картинок в одну также возможно в автоматическом режиме.